# How can I increase / remove the map size limit when editing a track in Trackmania Nations Forever?

Tags: trackmania-forever

When creating a track in Trackmania Nations Forever, the size of the stadium is limited. Is there any way to expand it, or even better remove the limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While utilities exist that allow players to edit tracks outside the game (these are used for 'block-mixing' tracks), there are currently no known methods to extend a track outside the bounds of the stadium.

Answer (score 3):

You can download **'tmunlimiter'**. It will give you 2 files (**the launcher** and **text file**). Put the launcher and text file in the same map as your normal tm launcher. When you use the tmunlimiter laucher it will lauch the game exactly the same, but when your going to editor you can mix blocks.
The text file is for expanding the stadium size. You can change the **32x32x32** to **256x256x256** for example. If you launch the tmunlimiter and you go to editor it will be that size. If you want to play the track online you have to use the tmulimiter laucher, **all the players who play with the normal laucher will be kicked out of the server** becouse the normal laucher dont allow it. This will not happend if you only use the blocks in the 32x32x32 size of the same style. **(Dirt blocks can be put outside the stadium, players without the laucher wont be kicked out the server)**

I hope this info will help u.

Gtz Prime.